# Ruby on rails Test for email validation for acceptable addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have some trouble with Rails validation

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.-COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
```

These are email addresses that are acceptable, but ever time I run bundle exec rake test:models

I get an error on USER@foo.-COM. What I found is when I remove this all my testing is good. Is there something wrong with the way that I typed in USER@foo.-COM this code.

Is there anybody with similar problem to my own.

Sorry the error in my terminal came out like this.

```
 FAIL["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", UserTest, 2015-09-15 12:13:17 -0400]
```

test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (1442333597.52s)
        "USER@foo.-COM" should be valid
        test/models/user_test.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserTest>'
        test/models/user_test.rb:37:in`each'
        test/models/user_test.rb:37:in `block in '

Comment: what's the error?  Maybe post your test

Comment: How is `USER@foo.-COM` valid? Doesn't that violate the specs?

Comment: Oh sorry the error was test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (1442333597.52s)
        "USER@foo.-COM" should be valid

Comment: To me it looked like syntax error

Comment: What do you mean by violate the specs?

Comment: `USER@foo.-COM` does not seem to be a valid email address.